# What is the meaning of a torque with respect to a point?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I'm studying the torque due to gravity and for the first time the text says "now referring to the torque due to gravity relative to the origin", but the body does not belong to the origin. Torque is not defined as the product of force times distance from the axis of rotation, but doesn't the axis of rotation have to belong to the body? The example was used to define the torque due to the force of gravity in an xy plane.
Should I perhaps imagine that the body is connected to a rod from the origin and take as the axis of rotation the one orthogonal to the plane and passing through the origin?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back to your basic understanding of angular momentum.

Neither angular momentum nor torque are properties of the motion of a body in isolation. They are properties of the motion of a body *with respect to a given fixed axis*. The axis can be anywhere at all and does not need to have anything to do with the body.

For example, a car driving in a straight line along a road has an angular momentum about an axis through any given lamp-post standing by the road. The angular momentum is $m d v$ where $d$ is the perpendicular distance from the lamp-post to the car's line of motion to the. More precisely,
$$
{\bf J} = m {\bf r} \times {\bf v}
$$

Similarly, a planet has an angular momentum about any axis you may care to pick. The Moon has an angular momentum about its own centre, and also an angular momentum about the centre of the Earth, and also an angular momentum about the centre of the Sun. They are all different. In each case there is a contribution from the Moon's rotation about its own axis, plus another contribution from the Moon's motion in space.

Similar statements apply to torque (which is equal to rate of change of angular momentum).